# How to build and run the TensorFlow Lite iOS examples?

Tags: ios, tensorflow-lite

How does one build and run the TensorFlow Lite iOS examples?

(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples)

Answer (score 5):

Here are instructions for building and running the following (22 Aug 2018) TensorFlow Lite iOS examples from both Source (Method 1) and Pod file (Method 2);

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/camera (classification with internal camera)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/simple (classification with image)

## How to get the TensorFlow Lite iOS camera/sample example to run [tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/camera / simple]

(e.g. camera classification models; `mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite`/`labels.txt`, simple classification models; `mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite`/`labels.txt`)

### Method 1 (Source: integrate with existing project)

Instructions based on; https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/ios.md

- `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- `git checkout r1.10` (select a version of tensorflow that contains tensorflow/contrib/lite/download_dependencies.sh)

  - [these instructions are based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.10 ]
- `cd tensorflow/contrib/lite`
- `./download_dependencies.sh`
- `./build_ios_universal_lib.sh`
- `cd examples/ios`
- `./download_models.sh` (download tensorflow models to `simple/data` and `camera/data`)
- Show the project navigator
- Update various settings in your app to link against TensorFlow Lite (see `tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/simple/simple.xcodeproj` / `camera/tflite_camera_example.xcworkspace` for example):

  - select [APPLICATIONNAME] project (blue document icon) - [default target] - Build Phases
  - Link Binary With Libraries - add (+) library `tensorflow/contrib/lite/gen/lib/libtensorflow-lite.a`
  - select [APPLICATIONNAME] project (blue document icon) - [default target] - Build Settings
  - Library Search Paths - add `[INSERTTENSORFLOWSOURCELOCATIONHERE]/tensorflow/contrib/lite/gen/lib`
  - Header Search paths - add `[INSERTTENSORFLOWSOURCELOCATIONHERE]` (the root folder of the tensorflow git repository)
  - Header Search paths - add `[INSERTTENSORFLOWSOURCELOCATIONHERE]/tensorflow/contrib/lite/downloads`
  - Header Search paths - add `[INSERTTENSORFLOWSOURCELOCATIONHERE]/tensorflow/contrib/lite/downloads/flatbuffers/include`
  - C++11 support (or later) should be enabled by setting C++ Language Dialect to GNU++11 (or GNU++14), and C++ Standard Library to libc++.
- project navigator - in [INSERTAPPLICATIONNAME] project (blue document icon) - create new group called `data`
- drag and drop `data` folder items from `tensorflow/contrib/lite/example/ios/simple/data` (`grace_hopper.jpg`, `labels.txt`, `mobilenet...`) to the newly created data folder in xCode (when asked, select Destination: Copy items if needed)
- modify the application's existing `AppDelegate.m` accordingly with `tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios/simple/AppDelegate.mm`/`.h` contents
- drag and drop source code items from `tensorflow/contrib/lite/example/ios/simple` (`ios_image_load.h`, `ios_image_load.mm`, `RunModelViewController.h`, `RunModelViewController.mm`, `RunModelViewController.xib` [NOT: `AppDelegate.h`, `AppDelegate.mm`, `main.mm`])

### Method 2 (Pod file)

Instructions based on; https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_ios

- `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`

  - OPTIONAL: `git checkout r1.10` / `5b63ee85acc0676a35252c50014a178b55aabaa4`
  - [these instructions are based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/5b63ee85acc0676a35252c50014a178b55aabaa4]
  - OPTIONAL: extract tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios folder from tensorflow
- `cd tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/ios`
- `./download_models.sh` (download tensorflow models to `simple/data` and `camera/data`)
- `cd camera`/`cd simple`
- `pod repo update`
- `pod install`
- `open tflite_camera_example.xcworkspace` / `open simple.xcodeproj`
- select `tflite_camera_example`/`simple` project (blue document icon) - [default target] - General
- select 'Automatically manage signing' (required for `simple` project)
- Change project developer to [INSERTDEVELOPERNAMEHERE]
- Build/run